# Converting a piece of C++ to Python

Tags: c++, python

I'm trying to convert this C++ to Python. I practice Python only and haven't touched C/C++ yet.

```
int phi(const int n)
{
  // Base case
  if ( n < 2 )
    return 0;

  // Lehmer's conjecture
  if ( isprime(n) )
    return n-1;

  // Even number?
  if ( n & 1 == 0 ) {
    int m = n >> 1;
    return !(m & 1) ? phi(m)<<1 : phi(m);
  }

  // For all primes ...
  for ( std::vector<int>::iterator p = primes.begin();
        p != primes.end() && *p <= n;
        ++p )
  {
    int m = *p;
    if ( n % m  ) continue;

    // phi is multiplicative
    int o = n/m;
    int d = binary_gcd(m, o);
    return d==1? phi(m)*phi(o) : phi(m)*phi(o)*d/phi(d);
  }
}
```

Most of it is straightforward to convert, it just requires looking up C++ operators. However, this bit:

```
      for ( std::vector<int>::iterator p = primes.begin();
        p != primes.end() && *p <= n;
        ++p )
```

What does it mean in Python?

Comment: It's just iterating through the array primes, stopping if the current value <= n

Comment: @therefromhere: "stopping if the current value <= n" - rather, stopping when the current value is NOT <= n.  @nebffa: in a C++ for loop, the first statement executes once, much as if it appeared on a line before the for loop, except that p is only in scope within the loop; the second part is like a `while()` loop condition - it must be true for the loop to run, even the first time; the last bit is executed after the loop tries to continue but before retesting the middle condition.  So, this iterates over the vector for primes up to `n`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy gah, sorry, brain fart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for p in primes:
  if p > n:
    break
   ...
```

or

```
for p in (x for x in primes if x <= n):
   ...
```

Although the former will end quicker.

Comment: And technically, the former is a more faithful translation, since the latter will behave differently if the primes vector is not sorted in increasing order (which I acknowledge, it probably is).